# ActorSystem expenses in play application

Tags: java, akka

I have a question , is it expansive for productivity, do `ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("System");` many times, or I must do this once and use one reference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create only one `ActorSystem`, from the [Akka doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/general/actor-systems.html):

> An ActorSystem is a heavyweight structure that will allocate 1…N Threads, so create one per logical application